# Problema al crear usuario

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, servidor

Estoy intentando crear un usuario mediante este comando grant:

```
GRANT ALL ON usuario.* to usuario@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'contrasena';
```

El problema es que no reconoce el fin de las comillas, por lo que reconoce que no se ha terminado de ejecutar. 
Si pongo otras comillas para que se cierre y se ejecute da error.

Comment: Esta dando permiso a un usuario, el cual aun no esta creado, primero debe crear el usuario `CREATE USER '{$usuario}'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '{$clave}';` y luego hacer el  `GRANT ALL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como planteaba en el comentario que le realicé esta dando permiso a un usuario, el cual aun no esta creado, primero debe crear el usuario:

```
CREATE USER 'usuario'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'clave';
```

Intente esto para darle acceso a la base de datos dbPrueba:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbPrueba.* To 'usuario'@'localhost';
```

Luego, para volver a cargar los permisos recién asignados, ejecute:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Ejemplo en una linea:

```
CREATE USER 'usuario'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'clave'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON baseDatos.* To 'usuario'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'clave'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Uso:

> - `GRANT`: Este es el comando utilizado para crear usuarios y otorgar derechos a bases de datos, tablas, etc.
> - `ALL PRIVILEGES`: Esto le dice que el usuario tendrá todos los privilegios estándar. Sin embargo, esto no incluye el privilegio de usar el comando `GRANT`.
> - `dbPrueba.*` Esta instrucción MySQL para aplicar estos derechos para su uso en toda la base de datos dbPrueba. Puede reemplazar el `*` con nombres de tabla específicos o guardar rutinas si lo desea.
> - `TO 'usuario'@'localhost'`: Es el nombre de usuario de la cuenta de usuario que está creando. Nota: debe tener las comillas simples allí. 'localhost' le dice a MySQL de qué `hosts` se puede conectar el usuario. Si solo lo quiere de la misma máquina, use `localhost`
> - `IDENTIFIED BY 'clave'`: Como habrás adivinado, esto establece la contraseña para ese usuario.

**Actualización:**

Compruebe los permisos que el comando anterior emitió para ese usuario ejecutando el siguiente comando.

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'usuario'@'localhost'
```

En los comentarios me dice que aunque se cree no lo deja acceder, intente crear el usuario una ves este logeado como `root`

```
$ mysql -u root -p -e "grant all privileges on baseDatos.* to
`{usuario}`@`{localhost}` identified by '{clave}'; flush privileges;"
```

ignore la opción **-p**  , si el usuario de `mysql` no tiene contraseña o simplemente presione el botón <kbd>Enter</kbd> para omitir.

Comment: Como he comentado arriba, me sucede lo mismo si quiero primero crear el usuario.

Comment: @JesusRedondo puedes mostrar cual es el error textual que te muestra?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/47pyf6g4tv7yagn/Comillas.JPG?dl=0

Aunque ponga que se ha ejecutado no es así porque no me deja entrar a dicho usuario

Comment: @JesusRedondo iniciaste sesión como `root`? : `mysql -u root` , intenta crear el usuario cuando este logeado como root primero.

Comment: Vale, lo siento muchísimo. El problema era que una parte de mi contraseña era \, por lo que estaba intentando reconocer el caracter siguiente como un caracter especial, tipo \n

Comment: @JesusRedondo ok, y revise he actualizado mi respuesta, Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Primero debes crear al usuario, por que si no estas asignando permisos a algo inexistente, del modo sigueinte

```
CREATE USER 'invitado'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'contrasenia';
```

Ahora una vez que esta creado asignas permisos

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'invitado'@'localhost';
```

Si deseas que el usuario solo acceda a una base de datos  especifica crea el comando asi

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'invitado'@'localhost';
```

Para finalizar ejecuta el comando siguiente para actualizar la tabla de usuarios y sus permisos

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

**¿QUÉ PRIVILEGIOS PUEDO OTORGAR A LOS USUARIOS?**

> 1. ALL PRIVILEGES
> 2. CREATE
> 3. DROP
> 4. DELETE
> 5. INSERT
> 6. SELECT
> 7. uPDATE

Comment: Creando el usuario primero tambien me sucede lo mismo, el problema reside en las comillas tras el IDENTIFIED BY. No me deja continuar

Comment: AGREGA EL ERROR QUE TE OCURRE POR QUE TODOS ESTOS CVOMANDOS LOLS EJECUITO EN CONSOLA SIN PROBLEMA @JesusRedondo

Comment: @JesusRedondo trta de seguir los comandos como te indico noto incosistencia en como los estas ejecutando checa paso a paso como lo indico

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/47pyf6g4tv7yagn/Comillas.JPG?dl=0

Aunque ponga que se ha ejecutado no es así porque no me deja entrar a dicho usuario

Comment: @JesusRedondo te faltan comillas en owncloud y localhost por eso te digo guiate con mis pasos

Comment: Vale, lo siento muchísimo. El problema era que una parte de mi contraseña era \, por lo que estaba intentando reconocer el caracter siguiente como un caracter especial, tipo \n

Comment: entendido, elige por favor cual respyuesta te fue util y calificala por favor @JesusRedondo

Comment: Claro.
Una cuestión, realmente no hace falta utilizar create user, el grant usado de esta forma también crea el usuario